How to know the tendencies from a dataset of two columns of categorical values

This is a dataset and my task is to find out the answer of the question: Do men tend to prefer Product A more compared to women?
How to approach? If there was numerical values in both columns we could use a scatter plot and then use correlation value to find that out. But here? Do I need to find the proportion values, like:
proportion of men bought Product A vs proportion of female bought product A
And then see which value is greater? Or is there any other approach? And if we want to test the hypothesis to check if this particular sample reflects the whole population, what kind of test I should use? I use Python.
